# How to replace FileName in SaveFileDialog.FileOk event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, interop, savefiledialog

I'd like to change the file name of the `SaveFileDialog` in the event handler attached to the `FileOk` event, in order to replace the file name typed in by the user with another file name in some cases, while **keeping the dialog open**:

```
var dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
...
dialog.FileOk +=
    delegate (object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dialog.FileName.EndsWith (".foo"))
        {
            dialog.FileName = "xyz.bar";
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    };
```

Stepping through the code shows that the `FileName` gets indeed properly updated, but when the event handler returns, the file name displayed in the dialog does not change. I've seen that I could theoretically use Win32 code like the following to change the file name in the dialog itself:

```
class Win32
{
   [DllImport("User32")]
   public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr);

   [DllImport("User32")]
   public static extern int SetDlgItemText(IntPtr, int string, int);

   public const int FileTitleCntrlID = 0x47c;
}

void SetFileName(IntPtr hdlg, string name)
{
    Win32.SetDlgItemText (Win32.GetParent (hdlg), Win32.FileTitleCntrlID, name);
}
```

However, I've no idea where I can get the `HDLG` associated to the `SaveFileDialog` instance from. I know I can rewrite the whole `SaveFileDialog` wrapper myself (or use [code like NuffSaveFileDialog](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1372296-2.php) or the [CodeProject extension of SaveFileDialog](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CustomizeFileDialog.aspx)), but I'd prefer to use the standard WinForms classes for technical reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the dialog handle I used reflection, then called `SetFileName` with that handle:

```
dialog.FileOk +=
    delegate (object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dialog.FileName.EndsWith (".foo"))
        {
            Type type = typeof(FileDialog);
            FieldInfo info = type.GetField("dialogHWnd", BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                                                       | BindingFlags.Instance);
            IntPtr fileDialogHandle = (IntPtr)info.GetValue(dialog);

            SetFileName(fileDialogHandle, "xyz.bar");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    };
```

N.B.: in your Win32 class you only need to define SetDlgItemText function (there is no need to `GetParent`) and pass to it the dialog handle:

```
    [DllImport("User32")]
    public static extern int SetDlgItemText(IntPtr hwnd, int id, string title);

    public const int FileTitleCntrlID = 0x47c;

    void SetFileName(IntPtr hdlg, string name)
    {
        SetDlgItemText(hdlg, FileTitleCntrlID, name);
    }
```

### EDIT:

To have the previous code working on Windows 7 (Vista also I think?), set the dialog's property `ShowHelp` to `true`:

```
dialog.ShowHelp = true;
```

the appearance will change a little bit, but I don't think it's a big deal.